# Getting error while creating an instance of JSONObject

Tags: android, json, eclipse, android-volley

I want to make an app that contains basic login facility, for this i am using volley in eclipse.I have a Login Screen, a Registration Screen and a Home screen (for logout purpose).

I am following steps as stated by AndroidHive.

In this my registration process runs fine.I can see the details enterd by user in my database.

The problem is When i,m pressing the registration button it should move to login activity after completing the user registering ,But after registering the user successfully it do nothing .

What i Have Tried:

As of my logcat,I figure this out that there is something wrong when i am trying to create an instance of JSONObject .

link to my logcat screenshot:
http://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/Z5P9

link to my registration codes

http://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/Z5PF

Comment: Can you post log output + code?

Comment: i can,t due to my reputation . but i have provided the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do some changes in your code .Remove the line "Enter code here" (you are using 000webhost.com for hosting your website) ,which is by default line for each page in 000webhost.com .

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshots (you should be able to edit your own posts with code by the way ;)), the response you get is not JSON at all. Instead it starts with: `[Enter code here]` after which some JSONObject follows.

Either wrap the whole thing in JSON or cut the beginning of before parsing.